# webviewglue nativedestroy view

Tags: android

I am opening the browser at a page from my app, the code for opening the browser is one I have used many times, but in this particular case, the browser never opens.

I keep getting the following messages at the end in logcat:

```
09-27 15:41:16.624: INFO/ActivityManager(1644): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://www.nyt.com cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity } from pid 9332
09-27 15:41:16.634: WARN/ActivityManager(1644): Duplicate finish request for HistoryRecord{4097ec10 com.test/com.test.MainScreen}
09-27 15:41:16.684: VERBOSE/http(4606): 15326478 main RequestQueue.resetWifiProxy, wifiProxy is null
09-27 15:41:16.684: ERROR/http(4606): RequestQueue.setProxyConfig, wifiProxy is null
09-27 15:41:16.784: DEBUG/webviewglue(4606): nativeDestroy view: 0x562af8
```

This is a part of a huge app with a native library.

This is the snippet that opens the browser:

```
String afterSubmitAction = "http://www.nyt.com";

Uri uri = Uri.parse(afterSubmitAction);
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
finish();
```

Comment: Maybe the browser is crashing, which may be due to a bug reacting on the page displayed. You should try a minimal example, open the same page with a minimalistic `WebView` application.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working fine at my side.So please check your internet connection.Please run your code on Edge if you are using wifi to check what cause this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to add a comment to your post..

What happens if you comment out the `finish();` ?
If the Browser doesn't close, then it's was because you finished the parent activity.

Try this?

```
String afterSubmitAction = "http://www.nyt.com";

Uri uri = Uri.parse(afterSubmitAction);
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```